# How to install OS X Mavericks if disk only has Windows on it?

Tags: macos, install

I have a MacBook Pro

How can I install OS X Mavericks if my HDD only has Windows on it?

Comment: Why not look at apple.com/osx/recovery and start there. Internet recovery is pretty simple to reinstall OS X.

Comment: i`ve edited the question i also tried your way, and it doesn`t work, i`m keeping down cmd+r and nothing happens

Comment: Perhaps edit in your hardware model - the year it was released is detail enough - see apple.com/support for help identifying your model of Mac if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Internet Recovery if the normal Recovery HD won't boot.

Boot whilst holding ⌘⌥R until you get the spinning globe.

Answer (score 0):

Since the disk only has Windows on it, then it will not have a recovery partition.  If your Mac is older than around 2012, then it will not have Internet Recovery Mode either.

Here are the steps to follow if you want to legally install Mac OS X on your hard drive on an early Mac.

(Note that while this will only work for early Mac's say 2010 or 2009 or older.  Newer macs will not allow you to install OS X 10.6.  In those cases you really need to locate your original install disks or hope that your version of the Mac has Internet Recovery Mode on it):

1. Purchase OS X 10.6 installation disks from Apple using this link:
   http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard
2. Wait for the discs to show up in the mail.
3. When they do show up, insert the first disk.  While powering up your mac, hold the C key until you are presented with an option of which disk to boot - select your DVD.
4. (Don't have a DVD drive?  Then sorry, there is no legal way to install OS X on your computer.)
5. Once you have 10.6 installed, you can upgrade to 10.6.8 over the internet by going to the Apple icon and clicking on Software Update.
6. Once you have 10.6.8 you will have access to the App store, where you will be allowed to upgrade to the latest OS X version (Currently El Capitan), only if you have a valid Apple ID.  You can only upgrade to the latest version, you cannot upgrade legally to any intermediate versions.

I want to make it crystal clear that, in your situation, you absolutely cannot legally have Mavericks installed on your Mac, unless you previously purchased Mavericks through the app store with your Apple ID.  Apple only allows you to purchase 10.6 or the bleeding edge latest, they do not allow you to purchase old versions of OS X.  You can download old versions of OS X, but only if you had previously upgraded to that particular version using your Apple ID.

Follow these steps below to load any version of Mac OS X on any computer at any time.  Note that these instructions are against Apple EULA:

1. Pirate a bootable DVD or bootable USB copy of the OS X version you want to have on your computer.
2. Put the DVD or USB stick into your Mac, boot your Mac, and it will install the pirated OS.
3. Your system will run exactly as if you legally purchased a disk.

Comment: Based on what are you claiming that using this method to install 10.8 or 10.9 would be against Apple EULA?

Comment: The problem with buying a 10.6 disc is that the OP's Mac has to support 10.6. For example, if it came installed with 10.7, you can't just install 10.6 and than upgrade to mavericks

Comment: Jules this is true, thank you.  I will amend the answer to reflect this concern.  It gets very very tricky... if you have a Mac from circa 2012 through 2014 then restoring it without the original discs will almost certainly mean needing to obtain a bootleg copy of the OS X on DVD or USB stick.  :-(

Comment: Patrix thank you for your edit of my answer.  :-)

Comment: Patrix I believe any bootlegging of DVD or bootable USB is against EULA.  The EULA-friendly way to restore a Mac:  1. Use original install disk that came with your machine, or 2. Use internet recovery mode if it's available, or 3. Use recovery partition if it was available, or 4. Purchase legal install disk direct from Apple.  5. Use a recovery disk or USB stick if you made such a recover disk or stick from your legitimate Mac before it crashed on you and 6. This is questionable, you may be able to purchase install disk from e-bay but it can be very difficult to tell legit OS X disk on ebay.